# Jenkins / Github webhook

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks

I am using Jenkins version 1.654 and Github Plugin 1.18.1 and Git Plugin 2.4.3.

I setup a Jenkins job, which can pull from Github repository and build successfully.

I am having trouble with the GitHub WebHook.  I enabled the "**Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" on the Jenkins Job, and setup a webhook on github using the format:

http://jenkinsuser:jenkinspassword@jenkins-server:8080/github-webhook/

When Github repo is changed, I see the following in the Jenkins log:

```
INFO: Received POST for https://github.com/orgname/reponame
Mar 22, 2016 9:15:58 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1 run
INFO: Poked Jenkins_Project_Name
```

However, the build is not kicked off.  It seems like everything is communicating correct, as Jenkins receives the notification from Github.

Github shows the payloads being delivered successfully.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Thanks

--T

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated:

> Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!

You could try [Generic Webhook Trigger](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin). It should be able to support the same use case but give better feedback on what is going on.

There are some use cases with GitHub here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/tree/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/github